# SharePoint List Person Column should not be blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I have a Person Column in my SharePoint List that is set to only show in the SharePoint List Form if the value of the Person column is not equal to the email address of the SharePoint List user.

My Person Column has a Conditional Formula. hence, I cannot set it as required. And there is no Column Validation field in the List Settings for Person Column.

Is there any other way to warn a user that the Person Column should not be blank? Validation Settings maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint Online out of the box functionalities because of following reasons:

1. You cannot apply conditional formula on list form fields if the the column is set as Required from column settings.
2. Person or Group columns are considered as a complex type column in SharePoint and SharePoint list validation formulas does not support using Person or groups column values.

For your requirements to show/hide person or group field and make it required conditionally, you will have to customize the list form using either Power Apps or SharePoint framework (SPFx).

For this specific requirement, I will suggest you to customize the list forms using Power Apps as it is easy, low-code and quicker solution.

Check below for more information:

1. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
2. [Power Apps - Make a column mandatory based on value of another column](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Make-a-column-mandatory-based-on-value-of-another-column/td-p/873211)